# Buffer an Unsigned Integer in Java

Tags: java, int, buffer, unsigned-integer

I am trying to add an unsigned integer in Java, I know they are not supported, but I feel they would help in our case and make it easier than a long.

I would like to make an int of getUInt(), etc.

Our current code:

```
//--- functions ---
public int unsigned(int index){
    byte b = buf[index];
    if (b>=0) return b;
    return 256 + b;
}

public void setInt(int index,int val){
    buf[index+0] = (byte)(val&0xff);
    buf[index+1] = (byte)((val>>8)&0xff);
    buf[index+2] = (byte)((val>>16)&0xff);
    buf[index+3] = (byte)((val>>24)&0xff);
}
public void setShort(int index,int val){
    buf[index+0] = (byte)(val&0xff);
    buf[index+1] = (byte)((val>>8)&0xff);
}

public int getInt(int index){
    return (buf[index+3]<<24) | (unsigned(index+2)<<16) | (unsigned(index+1)<<8) | unsigned(index+0);
}   
public int getShort(int index){
    return (buf[index+1]<<8) | unsigned(index+0);
}
public int getUShort(int index){
    return (unsigned(index+1)<<8) | unsigned(index+0);
}
```

How would I go about doing so, every time I get into the wrong buffer and get zeros.

Thanks for all your help,
-Michael

Comment: This code looks more-or-less right.  Can you provide an example of code that uses these functions that outputs the wrong answer?

Comment: Have you already looked at the java [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) class?

Comment: Wait a couple of weeks (Java 8) and you will have [unsigned integer support in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) --> `In Java SE 8 and later, you can use the int data type to represent an unsigned 32-bit integer, which has a minimum value of 0 and a maximum value of 2^32-1. Use the Integer class to use int data type as an unsigned integer. See the section The Number Classes for more information. Static methods like compareUnsigned, divideUnsigned etc have been added to the Integer class to support the arithmetic operations for unsigned integers.`